# "DirectoryOperationException: A value in the request is invalid" is thrown for one user when LDAP binding

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices

I'm using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LDAP to authenticate against an Oracle/Sun LDAP server. The code normally works fine, but for a very small number of users, I'm getting the following exception:

System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: A value in the request is invalid.
  at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.BindHelper(NetworkCredential newCredential, Boolean needSetCredential)

Here's the general algorithm that I'm following:

- Establish a connection to the ldap server. AuthType is Basic, AutoBind is disabled, LDAP Version 3.
- I bind using a "browser" username and password (an account created specifically so my program can retrieve information about users). I need to retrieve their information even if authentication fails, so I can't bind as the user right away.
- Retrieve information about the user.
- Call connection.Bind(new NetworkCredential(USERDN, USERPASS)) to re-bind using the user's credentuials. This works for over 99% of my userbase. I normally look for a DirectoryException with a message of "The supplied credential is invalid." to tell if the credentials were correct or not. However, with a few users, I get the "A value in the request is invalid" exception.

This exception is thrown for the handful of accounts every time they attempt to authenticate, so it doesn't seem to be a one time issue with the server.

Comment: Is it possible the users are either disabled, or intruder locked?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a pattern to it. Some users are locked out, some aren't.